# How to add BackgroundWorker to VSTO ThisAddIn.vb

Tags: vb.net, outlook-addin

I'm trying to build an Outlook VSTO addin (using VB.Net) to do some time consuming data searching which is also have a Form Window of to show the current status of the task running, For this I want to use BackgroundWorker but I'm not sure how to achieve this in proper way.  I tried to add a BackgroundWorker programmatically as in below code but its not working. whenever I open the Outlook in Visual Studio Debugger it straightly goes to `Application is in break mode` where debugger is not giving any reference to the exact error. As `ThisAddIn.vb` is a class file there was no drag-n-drop option to add the BackgroundWorker from visual studio `Toolbox`. Please help. Thanks.

```
Public Class ThisAddIn
    Shared WithEvents BackgroundWorker_Startup As BackgroundWorker
    Public Async Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
        Await Task.Delay(15000)
        AddHandler BackgroundWorker_Startup.DoWork, AddressOf BackgroundWorker_Startup_DoWork
        BackgroundWorker_Startup.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub BackgroundWorker_Startup_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker_Startup.DoWork
        'Call a function
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub BackgroundWorker_Startup_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker_Startup.ProgressChanged
        Form1.Label.Text = (CType(e.UserState, String))
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub BackgroundWorker_Startup_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker_Startup.RunWorkerCompleted
        If (e.Error IsNot Nothing) Then
            MsgBox(e.Error.Message)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If you can use `Async/Await`, why bother using a `BackgroundWorker`?

Comment: I though of using `Async/Await ` is to delay the starting of the task by certain amount of time like 10 - 20 minutes, The purpose to use `Await` is to wait this time period when users opens the Outloop App and sync/downloaded the new emails before starting the background functions of the Addin.

Comment: No, the point of `Task.Delay` is to delay. The point of `Async` and `Await` is to invoke an asynchronous task and wait for it to complete.  It's another way of implementing parallelism, which a `BackgroundWorker` is also.

Comment: @jmcilhinney : IMO a _**better**_ way, these days. ;)

Comment: @VisualVincent, I think the `BackgroundWorker` is still a good option for beginners in a WinForms app because it works in a familiar way, i.e. call a method and handle an event. Overall though, I would agree that `Async`/`Await`. is probably the only option people need to for virtually all their parallelism needs.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that Outlook Object Model cannot be used from a thread other than the main one. Starting with Outlook 2016, it will raise an exception as soon as it detects access from a secondary thread. Your only options are Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language - I am its author) - its [RDO](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm) family of objects can be used from a secondary thread (save the value of the `Namespace.MAPIOBJECT` from OOM on the main thread, create a new instance of the [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) object on the secondary thread, set its `MAPIOBJECT` property to the value saved on the main thread).

Windows controls also have thread affinity. In case of WinForms, that means you need to use [Control.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or Dispatcher object to make sure the code is executed on the main thread where the control was created.